# Couldn't establish a secure connection

Tags: tls, vpn, internet, trust, tls-intercept

NordVPN popped up with

> "Couldn't establish a secure connection." "We couldn't validate this
> TLS certificate and ensure a secure connection required for NordVPN to
> run. It looks like your internet traffic might be intercepted.
>
> ```
> Issued by: NetAlerts Services, O=NetAlerts
> Issued to: api-nc.napps-2.com, O=DNSFilter
> Valid from 8/7/2023 to 8/8/2023
> Thumbprint: 777EB9441518EC165CC08836DB49F6178CDE0630
> ```
>
> If you are sure that this certificate belongs to a program that you
> trust, e.g. an antivirus program, you can trust this certificate for
> now at your own risk."

I don't believe I have seen this before. I haven't clicked on anything weird. I know I've tried to get rid of the preinstalled McAfee antivirus to no avail. Probably need to boot up into a safe boot and uninstall it or delete that program; however, this certificate doesn't look like it's from McAfee.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Is your ISP or country you reside in known for making MitM attacks or something similar? If you're ok with that you may reveal your country and/or ISP so people could react with similar conditions etc

Comment: I was using Walmarts Wi-Fi and then switched over to Verizon hotspot. Neither ISP is known for MitM attacks that I’m aware of. I also live in the United States.